# using append flag to continuously append log causes service to fail

Tags: systemd, log

In my systemd service I used `append` to keep on appending log to exisint log file:

```
[Service]
Type=idle
Restart=always
RestartSec=6
EnvironmentFile=/home/rock64/.config/systemd/user/photon_uploader.env
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/iot/home_iot/tcpserver.py
StandardOutput=append:/var/log/user/photon_uploder.log
StandardError=append:/var/log/user/photon_uploader_error.log
TimeoutStopSec=5
```

but service fails with this error.

```
Nov 24 12:22:29 rockpro64 systemd[1336]: /home/rock64/.config/systemd/user/photon_uploader.service:16: Failed to parse output specifier, ignoring: append:/var/log/user/photon_uploder.log
Nov 24 12:22:29 rockpro64 systemd[1336]: /home/rock64/.config/systemd/user/photon_uploader.service:17: Failed to parse output specifier, ignoring: append:/var/log/user/photon_uploader_error.log
```

Comment: do these folders exist already?

Comment: yes, folders and files exist

Comment: @steeldriver https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#StandardOutput= "append:path is similar to file:path above, but it opens the file in append mode."

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen thanks yes I just found that - I wonder when it was added? perhaps the OP's version does not support it

Comment: That's what I suspect

Comment: It looks like it was added in 240 so should be available in Disco but not Bionic - https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/NEWS

Comment: so whats the alternative ?